# c# Should I use a service or just poll the database

Tags: c#

I don't know too much about services so if I am trying to do something they are not intended for please forgive me.

I am trying to wright dispatching software for a family member. They plan on starting with 3 or 4 dispatchers but it may scale in the future. I need the software to constantly (every 5 or 10 seconds at the very least) check and see if a new unhandled call has been placed when not in a call or  if they are in a call see if another dispatcher updated the call (due to a call in with additional information).

Which option would be better for the above scenario

A) Have a table in a database that tracks updates to calls/ new calls and poll it every 5 - 10 seconds from every instance of the software.

B) Have a service running on the machine that has the database and have that service take care of all SQL. Create an instance of each call in the service and then just ask the service if there are any changes or unhandled call.

If B, is it possible to create a delegate in the service that the software on another (networked) machine can subscribe to? If so where might I find information on doing that, I could not find anything on google.

Comment: It’s definitely better to have a server component handling things than polling. Depending on the platform (web, desktop application, something else?) there are several possible ways to go about it. Usually you’d keep a connection open to the server and push data when needed. But it’s a bit broad with this information so can’t really give any specific help.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? In particular, what's a "call" (phone, subroutine, RPC, ...)? What are you dispatching and to what are you dispatching that? I've read your question several times and I'm having a very hard time figuring what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of broad.

However, you can use the following:

- *DB Trigger* to watch for inserts etc, then do and fabulous db stuff when triggered.
- Create a *Windows Service* that polls, that's not a problem at all.

  - You could even self host a *WCF* server with a *Duplex Contract* that other software subscribes to, you could then send notifications etc via that channel.
  - or use *SignalR* for notification which would work just fine in this situation as well, and is a 5 minute job to get working.

Though, there is lots of approaches here; you really need to do some research to find what suits you most.

Comment: I definitely need to do more research but I think this is  probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Solution B is better.

> If B, is it possible to create a delegate in the service that the
>   software on another (networked) machine can subscribe to? If so where
>   might I find information on doing that, I could not find anything on
>   google.

It depends on your need and project type.

- You can use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr) in ASP.Net
- If you work with sockets you can keep connection alive and store client context in a list and notify theme